# More than one approval workflow in single workflow

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

Is it possible to call 3 approval workflows in a single list workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can create multiple approval workflow in single workflow.

See i have done three approval workflow in single workflow.

[image]

Hope you will get idea how to create multiple approval workflow in single workflow..

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.
You can check this link- http://sharepoint-community.net/profiles/blogs/sharepoint-2013-approval-workflow-with-3-dinamically-determined